# Define the return of a getter depending on a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, scope, getter, has-many-through

I'd like to change what the getter method returns based on a condition in Ruby on Rails 5.

I have:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  # has an boolean attribute :my_boolean
  has_many :bars, through: :FooBar, dependent: :destroy
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :foos, through: :FooBar, dependent: :destroy
  scope :my_scope, -> {where(some_attribute: true)}
end

class FooBar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Foo
  belongs_to :Bar
end
```

I want that if Foo has `:my_boolean` to `true`, when I call `foo.bars` it returns his bars within the scope `:my_scope`, and otherwise it returns all his bars.

I tried to override `Bar` getter without success like:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def bars
    bars = self.bars
    return bars.my_scope if self.my_boolean
    bars
  end
end
```

Any idea to make that work please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't name your `has_many` and your method the same way without having a `stack level too deep` exception (I suppose you've made a typo in your code, it should be `has_many :bars`, with a "s").

What you can do though is:

```
def my_boolean_bars
  return bars unless my_boolean

  bars.my_scope
end
```

Or use the same method as you've implemented, it seems ok to me.

**EDIT:**

If you want to keep the method name, you can do something like this:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars, through: :FooBar, dependent: :destroy

  alias_method :ori_bars, :bars

  def bars
    return ori_bars unless my_boolean
    
    ori_bars.my_scope
  end
end
```

Comment: I'll edit, you right in my code the has_many name is pluralized, I hoped I can use the has_many name instead of use a method. There is no way to do it this way ?

Comment: With my edited answer, you'll be able to keep the `bars` name. But I don't recommend it since no one will ever think the `has_many :bars` could be overridden after => it's guaranteed bugs.

Comment: I tried with alias_method and it works. Thanks for answer and both solution!